# Google Slides Elements Selection Order Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I was trying to get the selected shapes from the user's current selection in Google slides with Apps Script. The shapes return are not always match the user's selection order.

Example: Let's say we have 4 shapes on the slide, #1, #2, #3, #4. If I select #4, #2, #3, #1 on the slide one by one, the return result should match [shape#4, shape#2, shpae#3, shape#1]. However, I found sometimes the return result is a mess, not reflect the actual order I select. Not sure if this is a bug or something.

Here is my code to get the selected shapes to put them in a list.

```
function getSelectedShapes(){
    let shapes = []
    let selections = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection()
    let pageElementRange = selections.getPageElementRange()
    if (pageElementRange){
        let elements = pageElementRange.getPageElements()
        shapes = elements.map(element=>element.asShape())
    }
    return shapes
}
```

Comment: I could confirm about your issue. I'm not sure whether this is the bug or the current specification at Google side. So How about reporting this to Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) Although I had searched the same issue at Google issue tracker, I couldn't find it. So as the current answer, when several objects are selected on Google Slides, the order of elements retrieved by `getSelection().getPageElementRange().getPageElements()` is not the same with the order of selection by the bug or the current specification. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike we can say my this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172078/not-all-elements-convert-to-the-same-size-as-the-size-of-the-first-element also a selection bug in getPageElements() ? correct ?

Comment: @Puzzled Boy I saw [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172078/not-all-elements-convert-to-the-same-size-as-the-size-of-the-first-element). I think it's yes. In the current stage, it seems that this bug is still not resolved. By this, in your case, the 1st selected image cannot be retrieved. I think that this is the current reason of your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not all elements convert to the same size as the size of the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172078/not-all-elements-convert-to-the-same-size-as-the-size-of-the-first-element)

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @Tanaike, the method [`getPageElements`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/layout#getpageelements) returns the elements and shapes rendered on the page in no particular order and therefore you will not be able to retrieve them in any particular order.

As @Tanaike mentioned, you can make a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) asking for getting these elements in the order of your selection.